# Array of struct of arrays to 2D array

Tags: matlab, struct

I have the following array of struct:

```
item.Position=[];
item.Cost=0;
items=repmat(item,1000,1);
for i=1:1000
    items(i).Position = floor(ones(1,5)*rand*10);
    items(i).Cost = rand;
end
```

I want to extract the Position as 2D array. So, the result should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
9 2 4 1 0 3 4 
5 4 3 2 4 9 8
....
0 2 4 8 6 3 1
```

is it possible without looping in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collect the output of `items.Position` using `[]`. This will, however, collect it as one long array. So to obtain the matrix you will have to reshape it, i.e. something like

```
%Build data
item.Position=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
item.Cost=0;
items=repmat(item,1000,1);

%Collect output
tmp = [items.Position];

%Reshape
res = reshape(tmp,7,[]).';
```

The collection and reshape can of course be done in 1 step, I just divided it up for clarity.